# How to add an activity before MainActivity.java

Tags: android, android-studio, splash-screen

How do you add an activity (SplashActivity.java in my case) that launches automatically before the MainActivity? I've added in the below code but the activity is still being skipped over. I've already tried going to Edit Configurations -> Launch -> Default Activity. And the Splash Activity is the only activity with an intent filter.

**SplashActivity.java**

```
package com.example.simplesplashscreen;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.drawable.AnimatedVectorDrawable;
import android.graphics.drawable.Drawable;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;

import androidx.appcompat.widget.AppCompatImageView;

public class SplashActivity extends Activity implements InterfaceSplash {
    private AppCompatImageView image;
    private AnimatedVectorDrawable animation;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_splash);
        image = (AppCompatImageView) findViewById(R.id.splashobject);
        launchSplashScreen();
        dismissSplashScreen();
    }

    @Override
    public void launchSplashScreen() {
        super.onStart();
        Drawable d = image.getDrawable();
        if (d instanceof AnimatedVectorDrawable) {
            Log.d("testanim", "onCreate: instancefound" + d.toString());
            animation = (AnimatedVectorDrawable) d;
            animation.start();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void dismissSplashScreen() {
        // Start Main Activity
        startActivity(new Intent(SplashActivity.this,MainActivity.class));
        finish();
    }
}
```

**AndroidManifest.java**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    package="com.example.simplesplashscreen">

    <application
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.SimpleSplashScreen">
        <activity
            android:name=".SplashActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
                <category android:name="android.intent.category.DEFAULT" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
        <activity
            android:name=".SecondActivity"
            android:exported="true">
        </activity>
    </application>

</manifest>
```

Comment: You are starting another activity in onCreate and finish your current activity. 
Did you register your MainActivity in the manifest too?
If your only problem is, that your splashscreen is skipped you have to implement a delay before calling dismissSplashScreen()

Comment: Post entire manifest

Comment: I've added in the entire manifest